# How to send the data to one page to other page using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two pages with two grids,

in my first page I have 10 editable rows. and I have one next button.

I need to get all these 10 rows edited values to the next page to store the edited values to the other variable ID's in the next page. what is the best way to use this type of situations

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your editable rows inside of a `<form>` in the first view

```
// BeginForm will render a <form> around the rowmodel HTML
using (Html.BeginForm('PostToMe', 'MyController')) {
    foreach (RowModel row in Model) {
        // HTML to render out a row
    }
}
```

then send each row as an instance of a view model type with properties that match the data for each row

```
public class RowModel
{
    // properties here
}
```

Finally post a collection of those types to the controller action. e.g.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostToMe(IList<RowModel> rows)
    {
        // do something with rows
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC there is no notion of *Page*. There are controllers, actions and views. So probably what you are talking about is how to have a view send information to a controller action. Well there are couple of ways. One consist in generating an HTML `<form>` in this view, filling it with input elements and pointing this form action attribute to the target action:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("TargetAction", "SomeController")) { %>
    ... some input fields, maybe in a grid, whatever
    <input type="submit" value="GO" />
<% } %>
```

If you want to select a particular row in the grid then you could generate a form on each row in this grid and use the item id as hidden field.